# regex for file name with Asterisk

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a program (c# on Windows) that gets a file name from the user and look for it.

I tried to google for a valid file name regex with asterisk and could not find a sample.

I guess valid file names could be:

1. file.something
2. file?.something
3. file*.something
4. file*.*
5. file*.something*

Thanks!

Comment: it is just the file name. the folder is in a known location

Comment: `*` and `?` are not allowed characters in file names, at least on Windows platforms. Do you want to search by regex or a regex to ensure that the user provided a valid file name?

Comment: I know that these are not allowed characters.
But the user can put them so the program will return all files that match them.

Comment: I would like to use a regex to ensure that the input is ok 
e.g. not good file name could be : some*thing.txt

Comment: These are wildcards in your examples. So, probaly, you want to allow all characters that are not in `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` and the wildcard characters `?` and `*`.

Comment: @stribizhev A [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSkSeC) using `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need something like this: `^[a-z?*. ]+$` to limit what ever it is that the user can provide.

When you will have done that process, you would need to process the input string so that you can transform it into a proper regular expression. You would need to replace something like `*` with `.*?` (depending on the extent of your match). You would also need to escape character such as `.` (which the user will have provided).

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I ended up doing this : 

`   if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_?*. ]+$"))
         { 
            e.Handled = true;
         }`